# Tkinter / Making buttons as many as the number taken from the entry

Tags: python, python-3.x, button, tkinter, tkinter-entry

Okay, This is a weird title but here is the explanation. Im currently working on a small project and i want to create certain number of Tkinter-buttons that the number taken from Tkinter entry. For example , if i give to my entry "10" , it should create 10 button side by side.

This is my Label and Entry code:

```
self.number_of_buttons= Tkinter.Label(self.frame2, text="Number Of buttons :")
self.number_of_buttons.grid(row=0 , column= 2, padx=(25,10), pady = 15)
self.number_of_buttons_entry =Tkinter.Entry(self.frame2, text="a" , bd=1,relief="sunken", width = 15)
self.number_of_buttons_entry.grid(row=0,column=3)
```

And This is the example of my button code:

```
self.button = Tkinter.Button(self.table, text="1", font="Helvetica 8 bold", width=15, height =5)
self.button.grid(row=0, column=0)
```

(ps: button locations are not important right now, i just wanna figure out how can i do this)

Comment: Do you know how to handle an event from a Entry - in other words to make your program do something when the user types something into the Entry and hits Enter?  If you do, just create the desired number of buttons in the event handling code.  If you don't, then either learn how to do that or ask a different question

Answer (score 0):

This should help get you on your way.

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk ()
button_list = []
number_of_buttons = 7
for index in range (number_of_buttons) :
    button_list.append (Button (root, width = 10))
    button_list [index].config (text = str (index + 1))
    button_list [index].pack ()
root.mainloop ()
```

Comment: what if i want to make my button position like This  [link](https://ibb.co/7VFFVy4) 
 @bashBedlam